# How to create a table with Interval as primary key in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a table for handling billing frequencies using the SQLAlchemy ORM and I can't seem to get it to be happy

The following works great in Postgres:

```sql
create table test_interval(
    frequency interval primary key
);


insert into test_interval values ('1 MONTH'), ('1 YEAR');


select * from test_interval;
-- 0 years 1 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
-- 1 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
```

And I'm now trying to achieve the same thing in SQLAlchemy with this code

```py
from typing import Any

from sqlalchemy import Column, Interval, PrimaryKeyConstraint
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative, declared_attr


@as_declarative()
class Base:
    id: Any
    __name__: str

    # Generate __tablename__ automatically
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls) -> str:
        return cls.__name__.lower()



class BillingFrequency(Base):
    __tablename__ = "billing_frequency"
    # I've also tried this
    # __table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint("frequency"),)
    # frequency: Column(Interval(native=True), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    frequency: Column(Interval(native=True), primary_key=True, nullable=False)


# seed.py
# -- I've not even managed to create the table so this is yet untested --
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert

from app.models import BillingFrequency

def seed_billing(db: Session) -> None:
    # Monthy frequency
    stmt_month = insert(BillingFrequency).values(frequency="1 MONTH")
    stmt_month = stmt_month.on_conflict_do_nothing(
        index_elements=[BillingFrequency.frequency],
    )
    db.add(stmt_month)
    # Year frequency
    stmt_year = insert(BillingFrequency).values(frequency="1 YEAR")
    stmt_year = stmt_year.on_conflict_do_nothing(
        index_elements=[BillingFrequency.frequency],
    )
    db.add(stmt_year)
    db.commit()
```

Which results in the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class BillingFrequency->billing_frequency could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'billing_frequency'
```

And if I try to use primary-key using `__table_args__` I get the following error.

```
 KeyError: 'frequency'
```

Not sure how to handle this. It's quite trivial in pure SQL but the ORM makes it a pain.

Comment: In your class definition, try `frequency = ` instead of `frequency: `

Comment: Hehe, yep I realised that after tearing my hair for a good hour or two on this. Feels stupid when you see your error. I had also made another error in the seeding. 

I did add an answer in case someone sees this and are experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made two minor errors, but the error messages are unfortunately a bit cryptic for this type of error.

The first problem is that you've used `...: Column` i.e. as a type instead of `...= Column`, assigning a value. This is what causes the `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError` and the `KeyError: 'frequency'`, SQLAlchemy doesn't know that the column exists since it doesn't look in the type annotations for Column data.

The second error you've made is to use `db.add(…)` for a statement, you should instead use `db.execute(…)`. You would get this following error with `db.add`:

```
AttributeError: 'Insert' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
...
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.dml.Insert' is not mapped
```

With these changes your code should look like this:

```py
from typing import Any

from sqlalchemy import Column, Interval, PrimaryKeyConstraint
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative, declared_attr


@as_declarative()
class Base:
    id: Any
    __name__: str

    # Generate __tablename__ automatically
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls) -> str:
        return cls.__name__.lower()



class BillingFrequency(Base):
    __tablename__ = "billing_frequency"
    frequency = Column(Interval(native=True), primary_key=True, nullable=False)


# seed.py
# -- I've not even managed to create the table so this is yet untested --
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert

from app.models import BillingFrequency

def seed_billing(db: Session) -> None:
    # Monthy frequency
    stmt_month = insert(BillingFrequency).values(frequency="1 MONTH")
    stmt_month = stmt_month.on_conflict_do_nothing(
        index_elements=[BillingFrequency.frequency],
    )
    db.execute(stmt_month)
    # Year frequency
    stmt_year = insert(BillingFrequency).values(frequency="1 YEAR")
    stmt_year = stmt_year.on_conflict_do_nothing(
        index_elements=[BillingFrequency.frequency],
    )
    db.execute(stmt_year)
    db.commit()
```